# Why can't I loop in ReactJS

Tags: node.js, arrays, reactjs

I know I need to wait for the return for the fetch.

Which I can do in return() however I seem not to be able to do it in:

```
  render() {
    {!this.state.heat ?(
    this.items = this.state.heat.map((item) =>
    <li>{item.location[0].coordinates[0]}</li>
    );)}
```

Just before the return.

I need to call {items} inside the return.

How can I solve this?

```
export default class Heatmap extends Component {
  state = {
    loading: true,
    heat: null,
  }

  async componentDidMount(){
    const url = "http://localhost:3010/api";
    fetch(url).then(response => 
      response.json().then(data => ({
          data: data,
          status: response.status
      })
    ).then(res => {
      this.setState({heat: res.data})
      console.log(res.status, res.data)
    }));

  }

  render() {
    {!this.state.heat ?(
    this.items = this.state.heat.map((item) =>
    <li>{item.location[0].coordinates[0]}</li>
    );)}
      return (
      <div>
        {!this.state.heat ? (<div>Loading...</div>) : (
        <div>
          <LoadScript
        googleMapsApiKey="AIzaSyB65TiJzvcRXQ0XyDt_0B8IyX2CqYLEnQI"
      >
        <GoogleMap
          mapContainerStyle={containerStyle}
          center={center}
          zoom={10}
        >
          { /* Child components, such as markers, info windows, etc. */ }
          <></>
        </GoogleMap>
      </LoadScript>
      <ul>
      {this.items}
     </ul>
    </div>
      )}
        </div>

      
    )
  }
}
```

Comment: is your code get complied failed ? You used ternary operator without the part after `:`. In this case, I think it should be `{!this.state.heat && ...}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First thing, Format your code, so it would be easy to find where we're doing mistake if any. I don't see any error in your code other than formatting. I did some formatting, you can try this

```
render() {
  const { heat } = this.state
  if (!heat) return (<div>Loading...</div>)
  const items = heat.length ? heat.map(item => (
    <li>{item.location[0].coordinates[0]}</li>
  ) : []
  return (
    <div>
      <LoadScript googleMapsApiKey="AIzaSyB65TiJzvcRXQ0XyDt_0B8IyX2CqYLEnQI">
        <GoogleMap mapContainerStyle={containerStyle} center={center} zoom={10} >
          { /* Child components, such as markers, info windows, etc. */ }
        </GoogleMap>
      </LoadScript>
      {
         items.length && (
          <ul>
            { items }
          </ul>
         )
      }
    </div>
  )
}
```